# Get a part of a html file in java

Tags: java, html, regex, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have a HTML file looking like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foobar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    bla bla<br />
    {[CONTAINER]}
      Hello
    {[/CONTAINER]}
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the "Hello" in the Container out of the rest of the html file? I've done this in PHP years ago and i remember a REGEX-Function which calls a definde class-function and give the content of the container as a parameter.

Can someone tell me how to do this in Java?

Comment: @user2029057: Can you state what assumption that we can make about your text?

Comment: There are many ways that HTML will trip up attempts at using RegEx. The canonical post is [a well known StackOverflow post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), for example handling tag attributes. @Nikita's answer covers it pretty well. The OP is free to use a regex but it would be wise to be careful of the many edge cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex that matches everything between `{[CONTAINER]}` and `{[/CONTAINER]}`. Example:

```
// Non capturing open tag. Non-capturing mean it won't be included in result when we match it against some text.
String open = "(?<=\\{\\[CONTAINER\\]\\})"; 

// Content between open and close tag.
String inside = ".*?"; 

// Non capturing close tag.
String close = "(?=\\{\\[/CONTAINER\\]\\})";

// Final regex
String regex = open + inside + close;

String text = "<html>..."; // you string here

// Usage
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String content = matcher.group().trim();
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

But you must be careful. Because it works only for `{[CONTAINER]}` and `{[/CONTAINTER]}`. Attributes for this custom tags aren't supported.

You also must be aware that it doesn't handle html tags in any specific way. So if there is a html tags between your `CONTENT` tags - they will be included.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question instead of jumping on the _"don't parse html with regexes"_ bandwagon.

Comment: Another thing is that it doesn't care whether there is any HTML markup between them, if any.

Comment: thanks for everyone who wrote! That it was :)

Comment: you only have to write every \ twice then it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the HTML using jsoup , more help [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string)

More detailed [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

Comment: He's not asking to parse HTML, he's asking to obtain some text from between 2 very specific tags.

Comment: of course update with more detailed link

Comment: You're still talking about HTML parsing, there.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want using Java? 
You can simply use the DOM API with JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("id_container").firstChild.data; // beware of \n char
```

or in a less efficient way:

```
document.getElementById("id_container").innerHTML;
```

However if your file is building on the server you can also use the same API:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html

Comment: He's not asking to parse HTML, he's asking to obtain some text from between 2 very specific tags.